# "Recommend to have" vs. "recommend having"

Tags: word-choice, infinitives, gerunds, gerund-vs-infinitive

I am writing my bachelor dissertation and several times Microsoft Word has corrected me from "to have" to "having". One of the sentences, for instance, goes like this:

> The author recommends **to have** ‘(...)'. Bugeja further recommends **having** a student blog where prospective...

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: @choster: Agreed - but unless I'm much mistaken, the answer there doesn't specifically mention ***recommend*** (which I personally think sounds dated/archaic with the infinitive, but inarguably both forms *do* occur).

Answer (score 2):

Particular English verbs require particular kinds of grammatical structure for their objects.

If the person who is to take the action is expressed, *Recommend* takes either a *that* clause or an infinitive:

> I recommend that you read this carefully.
>
> I recommend you to read this carefully.

But if the person is not expressed, it takes a noun phrase with a gerund (*-ing*) form:

> I recommend reading this carefully.

There is no point in looking for a reason for this: it just happens to be a fact about the word *recommend* in current English. (*Require* and *advise* have the same pattern; *suggest* is similar, but won't take the *to* form; *want* takes only the *to* form).

Comment: Colin's explanation is quite clear. I agree with him. It is especially important to remember that _recommend_, _suggest_, _advise_ and _propose_ all function this way (like recommend+verb+ing), when they mean advise someone to do something. However, these words may mean others and such usage of gerund can be wrong.

Comment: #3 = -ing affix on “read” allows us to avoid “you” and ‘this’ gets more importance, highlighting content matter more than the action of ‘reading’. 

#1  ‘read this’ is the focus, and ‘that’ is subjunctive mood (only, more detectable in English when the verb need be inflected:  “… that he read it carefully.”   (verb, base form, and without S) 

#2, my least preferred, one needs an object (“you”) and then 
what follows is an “infinitive clause”, conveying purpose ( ∴ ‘to read’) when, really, the purpose is to understand what one is reading, not the reading itself.

Comment: I agree that I like #2 less than the others (but with _advise_ it would be my preferred form). I don't agree that there is any difference in emphasis between #1 and #3; nor do I agree that the "to" clause in #2 is a purpose clause.