# Is there any differences between "I suggest doing" and "I suggest you do?"

Tags: meaning, grammar

I know that both "I suggest doing this" and "I suggest you do this" are grammatically correct. But I wonder if they have same meaning or there are subtle difference between them.

Comment: The second sentence uses the *mandative subjunctive mood*, but otherwise they seem to be similar in meaning.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_present_subjunctive

Comment: The difference is that the second one mentions "you", which makes it more explicit *who* you expect to do the doing.

Comment: The phrase, "I [suggest *that*](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv201.shtml) you do this" is more formal.

Comment: One could point out that 'I suggest you do this' need not be the mandative subjunctive, which undermines the position of those who say that the mandative subjunctive should be used to avoid ambiguities.

Comment: @hobbs: In my vernacular that would be *who you expect to be [**doing the do.***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22doing+the+do%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: @FumbleFingers *Suggest* + finite clause doesn't seem to be covered in that question and answer. Have you got a better link?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, exactly so. Cold be either present simple or the subjunctive.

Comment: Perhaps I should have cited [“Recommend to have” vs. “recommend having”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140163/), which is itself closed in favour of [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/) (there's an excellent answer on the latter).

Comment: @FF Nice to see you're not letting your super-powers make you into a little dictator. ('Poland was possibly a mistake, says ...')